# Templates in C++ public function

Tags: c++, templates

I'm going through some C++ learning and I am tackling [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-class-templates?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) question on Hackerrank.

I think I understand how templates work and the example given, except for one line:

```
template <class T>
class MyTemplate {
    T element;

public:
    MyTemplate (T arg) { element = arg; }  //what does this line do? 
    T divideBy2 () { return element/2; }
};
```

Comment: It is the constructor

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++? This is elementary.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm starting to wonder if there should be a "c++ books to avoid" page...

Comment: @UKMonkey: Web browsers cannot yet handle the volume of characters required to display such a page.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit to be honest I've just been doing things online and looking up bits I don't understand. I know it's pretty lazy and not the most constructive way. Is there a particular resource you can recommend?

Comment: "Accelerated C++: Practical Programming by Example" is still a good (if old and therefore slightly out of date) book

Comment: @MoultoB: **[The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)**

Comment: @MoultoB: The problem with "looking up bits I don't understand" is that you are probably missing a load of important details that you don't _know_ you don't understand. So you don't look them up, and you go on not knowing. You should structure your learning. People spend a lot of time and effort putting together proper structured courses for people like you to study and learn from, and it's not for fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
MyTemplate(T arg){ element=arg; }
```

is the definition of `MyTemplate`'s constructor, taking a `T` argument *(where `T` is known at the moment of instantiation of the class - e.g. `MyTemplate<int>` -> `T` is `int`)* and assigning the `this->element` field to `arg` in its body.

Comment: you might want to mention that he better used the initializer list, that will make the template also work for `T`s that are not default constructible